# Rotate marker according to the driving direction and pointing to the driver with car icon in google map in my webpage

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps-markers

Can anyone suggest me the code for google maps where I can rotate the marker ( ex: car icon ) according to the driving direction.

I am using travel mode direction google map is it suitable for
for my requirement?

Below the screenshot which i need

Start and end point will be fixed and car icon will be rotate

[image]

I have the output from API and need to show in website Below API return:

```
[senderLati] => 39.93057688932532
[senderLong] => -75.29201399534941
[receiveLati] => 39.95255749635647
[receiveLong] => -75.17580829560757
[LatiNowDriver] => 39.9006933
[LongtNowDriver] => -75.2901483
[DriverDirection] => [{"latitude":39.90049,"longitude":-75.29041},{"latitude":39.90075,"longitude":-75.29076},{"latitude":39.90075,"longitude":-75.29076}]
[time] => 11
```

Thanks